# Interaction between the Menu Item (of Status Bar) and RecyclerView Item?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I've populated a recyclerview via JSON response from a server.

The recyclerview items consist of an image and time. There's also a button whose visibility is set to invisible.

[image]

*This is how each item looks with the button (also edit) visible*

Now, there is an edit button in the menu item (of the app) on click of which I want to set all the recyclerview item buttons visible.

How could I achieve this? I tried searching for the same but to no avail.

EDIT:

This the item code in the Schedule Fragment where the RecyclerView is displayed.

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()) {

        case R.id.action_edit:
            //onClick of edit menu item

            return true;

        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

This is the  ViewHolder class in ScheduleAdapter

```
    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    private NetworkImageView imageView_status;
    private TextView textView_status;
    private TextView textView_time;
    private Button button_edit;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        imageView_status = (NetworkImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        textView_status = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView_Status);
        textView_time = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView_Time);
        button_edit = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.button);
    }
}
```

This is the onBindViewHolder of the ScheduleAdapter

```
    public void onBindViewHolder(final CustomScheduleListAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    if (imageLoader == null) {
        imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();
    }

    holder.imageView_status.setImageUrl(punches.get(position).getImageURL(), imageLoader);
    holder.textView_status.setText(punches.get(position).getStatusName());
    holder.textView_time.setText(punches.get(position).getTimings());

    holder.button_edit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(final View v) {
            //Actions performed after button click
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Post the relevant code.

Comment: @KNeerajLal Done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have a field in the Adapter that keeps track of whether the `RecyclerView` items should be set to visible or not. Then in `onBindViewHolder` you set the visibility of the views based on it. Lastly in `onOptionsItemSelected` you set the value of that field in the adapter and call `notifyItemRangeChanged` on it.

For example:

Adapter:

```
public class ScheduleAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomScheduleListAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private boolean showAllViews = false;

    public void setShowAllViews(boolean show) {
        showAllViews = show;
        notifyItemRangeChanged(0, getItemCount());
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(CustomScheduleListAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.viewyoucareabout.setVisibility(showAllViews? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
    }
}
```

Schedule Fragment:

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()) {

        case R.id.action_edit:
            adapter.setShowAllViews(true);    
            return true;

        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: Man, this is EXACTLY what i wanted! Worked like a charm. Thank you so much!